# Combining Module Configurations in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

First, thanks for reading.

I'd like to have `Modules` that have a particular configuration key in their local configs (an array of strings to be simplistic), contribute these strings to the `Application` when needed.  I want to use it to define all available RBAC rules for this particular app, for very specific JSON calls that the app performs across its many modules (that have this key!).

Here's an envisioned config in a `module.config.php` for a fictitious Marketing module:

```
'rule_list' => array(
    'title' => 'Marketing',
    'asset' => 'marketing',
    'sections' => array(
        'statistics' => array(
            'title' => "Day-To-Day",
            'parts' => array(
                array( 
                    'title' => 'Statistics',
                    'asset' => 'marketing-statistics',
                    'route' => 'marketing/index/dashboard',
                    'description' => 'Inside view into marketing activity statistics and measurements'
                )                
            )
        )
    )
),
```

The `Application` module would have a `Controller` with a `listPermissionsAction` that I was hopeful could quickly reference all of these configs, and use them to render a view

But what's the best strategy?  I want to avoid having the modules push their configs out to the App onInit, because this would de-DRY my code.  The config inclusion should suffice.

Thanks for your guidance as always.

To clarify...

Looking for lines I can efficiently use to generate an array from the set of all Modules in the app with that particular config key.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you'd want to have your RBAC-Stuff inside the Database or separate FileSystem and just call them when needed. Where exactly is your problem in having all configuration merged together?

Comment: not sure if I am reading this correctly but ZF2 automatically combines the modules configs into one, dump this $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');